# Angularjs - Jasmine scope variable undefined in test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test my AngularJs code.

My controller is shown here:

```
'use strict';
(function() {
     angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('TestController', function($scope, $http, Auth, myService, $state) {
        try{
              $scope.testVar  = "Hello";
        }catch(e){
           console.log(e);
        }
     });
});
```

My test code is below:

```
'use strict';

 describe('Controller: TestController', function () {

     beforeEach(module('myApp'));

     var TestController, scope;

     beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        TestController = $controller('TestController', {
             $scope: scope
        });
      }));

     it('should testVar to be defined', function () {
       expect(scope).toBeDefined();
       expect(scope.testVar).toBeDefined();
      });
});
```

When I run it, it failed test with

> Expected undefined to be defined

I don't know what I am doing wrong ...

I already checked many post on SO but didn't get it resolved yet.

Comment: Instead of 'scope', try 'TestController.scope'

Comment: then it says ` TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object`

Comment: console.log(e) logs error to browser - you will not see that error in your test. You can try debug using alert: alert('Error occured: ' + e), that will output error to output you see in test.

Comment: there is no any issue in console.log(e), that is controller code and which works fine. i have issue with my test code, when i run `karma start karma.conf.js` then it will give test results.

Comment: By putting logger can you check your actual controller code is being executed or not while you run your test case ?

Comment: log in controller is working.

Comment: if i print `console.log($scope.testVar);` then its value printing in console while running test.

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya check my answer. Did it work for you?

Comment: Actually in there was some code in my controller which became false before reach to this condition, that's why this problem occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly issue is related to your variable declaration. You have declared ManualBookingController, but then you use TestController for the $controller line. Change ManualBookingController to TestController, see if that works.

Comment: sorry that was my typo, i correct that, still its not working

Answer (score 0):

I took your code almost as is, put it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tanmayrajani/jqo7u966/3/), test passes just fine. What I think might be missing in your case is you have some dependencies that are present in your controller but not mocked while creating the mock controller using `$controller` in your test suite. I removed them from your original controller (for now) and it worked fine.

And in order to mock `$state` (provider) and other services, you can see this [same example fiddle passing with dependencies injected](http://jsfiddle.net/tanmayrajani/jqo7u966/5/) and read about [underscore wrapping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject#resolving-references-underscore-wrapping-).

---

Also, keep in mind that sharing exact details on your question is very important. When I ran your test suite with your exact code, it first gave me following error:

> `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state` http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider%20%3C-%20%24state

..which is not mentioned in your question at all. You mentioned only the next error `Expected undefined to be defined` which was very common and less-useful to imagine what's going on.